# Custom Style number format in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Display number format

> Input: String like "4.5123"
>
> Want to Output : (4.5) But got output 4.5

following changes applied.
[image]

I want to output with brackets like **(4.5)** But as per above change get output 4.5 without brackets

What need to do for that?

Comment: You need all positive numbers to be displayed in brackets? what about -ve numbers how do you want them to be displayed? (-4.5)?

Comment: @Zeina, Yes I want to all positive number and -ve numbers like (4.5) or (-4.5). Also I have set Negatives format like (123) . It is wrong. It should be -123. I was just with that.

Comment: What is the formula for if I have input "4.5123" then I can convert to (4.5) using Formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a *Text Object* (the one with 'ab' on it as a symbol) on the report. Type a set of parenthesis into the text object, then drag and drop `{YourField}` into it. This will display the value with brackets.

To Format the number field in the text object, right click on it and choose *Format {YourField}*. Set Rounding to 0.1 and Decimals to 1.0 to meet your needs.

*Or* add Display String in *Format Editor -> Common*

```
'( '+ ToText(Round({YourField},1),"0.0") + ' )'
```

Comment: Yes, But need to convert "4.5123" to 4.5